# When (and how often) will the public Internet preclude WebSocket connections?

Tags: spring, flutter, networking, websocket

The [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-fallback) says:

> Over the public Internet, restrictive proxies outside your control may preclude WebSocket interactions, either because they are not configured to pass on the Upgrade header or because they close long-lived connections that appear to be idle.

The second problem can be overcome by heart-beat packages. However, how often will the first problem come up in *today's world* (2020.03)? Is it never a problem today, or still a big problem?

In addition, will there be other problems that make me not able to use a WebSocket?

P.S. I am using the WebSocket client in Flutter so browser support is not a problem.

Thanks very much for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there are still real-world cases where WebSockets don't work, even if not so frequently as in the past. A typical example is when you are behind a corporate proxy/firewall that does not support WebSockets (many BlueCoat installations have this issue). There are also some transparent proxies blocking WebSockets, even if this typically applies to unencrypted connections. If you go for WSS (WebSockets over TLS), most network intermediaries will not have issues with WebSocket setup, unless they decrypt all the traffic by injecting a custom certificate in the clients (as it happens on some corporate network). Then, bidirectional heartbeats can be useful to make sure the intermediaries do not close an idle WebSocket.

As a general suggestion, if your application is mission-critical, you should always provide a fallback transport in case WebSockets do not work. Fallback transports include HTTP streaming and HTTP long polling.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will use WSS then :) By the way, I think if an intermediary inject a certificate, the Android or iOS will not be happy about that, and throw some kind of errors saying "you have a untrusted certificate", so I do not worry about that?

Comment: @ch271828n: I *think* there are ways around this if the device is managed by a corporation. On Android at least that can lead to a permanent, non-dismissable notification that effectively reads "note that your company can read all your network traffic", heavily implying that in this case they do accept such an injected root certificate.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes I also see that when using Fiddler to capture the data packages. So I think most of the application users will not really do that. Thanks!